# Add Additional (Term Reference) Field to repeating Date & Time Field for Locations

Tags: 7, nodes, datetime, entities

So I have a question that I am not quite sure how to handle in Drupal. (I come from a Wordpress background).

So I have an Event Content Type. 
In this event CT I have a repeating Date/time field and I need each date/time field to be connected to its own Location. (All locations are stored in a Taxonomy called "Venues")

For Example, I could have 3 events on June 6th. Each at separate times but all three at different locations. So rather than create 3 Event nodes. I just want to set the three times and dates in one node.

Any idea's how to go about this? I was thinking I could do some type of field attach but I am not quite sure if that would be the way to go about it or to even start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you could fix this quite easily by creating a field collection

The field collection would contain the repeating date field and the term reference field.

When you add the field collection to your event content type, you can select to allow an unlimited amount of values.

I hop this can get you started?

If you should have any problem, just let me know.
I will add some screenshots then. Im posting from mobile phone now...

Good luck!